# How to get a scatter plot of mixture data with different shape and colour for each distribution?

Tags: r

I am running a simulation of mixture data. My function is harder than Gaussian distribution. Hence, here, I simplified my question to be in Gaussian form. That is, if I simulated a mixture data like this:

```
  N=2000
 U=runif(N, min=0,max=1)
 X = matrix(NA, nrow=N, ncol=2)
         for (i in 1:N){
              if(U[i] < 0.7){
               X[i,] <-   rnorm(1,0.5,1)
                    } else {
               X[i,] <- rnorm(1,3,5)
      }
 }
```

How can I have a scatter plot with different colour and shape (type of the plot point) for each cluster or distribution? I would like to have this manually since my function is hard  and complex.  I tried `plot(X[,1],X[,2],col=c("red","blue"))` but it does not work.

Comment: What is `N`? I ran your code and it didn't work because that object wasn't defined.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. N is the number of data point. I edit my question.

Comment: where are the clusters or groups in your data?

Comment: The group is the two different Gaussian. That is 0.7 of my data follow normal distribution with mean 0.5 and standard deviation =2. The other group is normal with mean 1 and standard deviation =3. That is. 'X[,1] and X[,2].

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Note that I had to do a bit of guesswork here to figure out what was going on, because your example code seems to have an error in it, you weren't generating different x1 and x2 values in each row:

```
N=2000
U=runif(N, min=0,max=1)
X = matrix(NA, nrow = N, ncol=2)
for (i in 1:N){
    if(U[i] < 0.7){
        # You had rnorm(n=1, ...) which gives 2 identical values in each row
        # Change that to 2 and you get different X1 and X2 values
        X[i,] <-   rnorm(2, 0.5, 1)
    } else {
        X[i,] <- rnorm(2, 3, 5)
    }
}

df = data.frame(
    source = ifelse(U < 0.7, "dist1", "dist2"),
    x = X[, 1],
    y = X[, 2]
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = source, shape = source)) +
    geom_point()
```

Result:

[image: Scatter plot]

Comment: Thank you so much. My code is very complicated and need a lot of understanding of my function. Hence I included this simple one. I tried 'ifelse' but I used the value of 'X[,1]' instead of U. I will try and see. Thank again.

Comment: As I understand n=1 run the for loop to generate the data, one value at each time.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got, but I'm not sure if this what you are looking for - the location of the observations for both clusters are exactly the same.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(X = X, U = U)
df <- gather(df, key = cluster, value = X, -U)
ggplot(df, aes(x = X, y = U, colour = cluster)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~cluster)
```

[image]

EDIT: I don't seem to be understanding what you are looking to map onto a scatter plot, so I'll indicate how you need to shape your data in order to create a chart like the above with the proper X and Y coordinates:

```
 head(df)
            U cluster          X
 1 0.98345408     X.1  2.3296047
 2 0.33939935     X.1 -0.6042917
 3 0.66715421     X.1 -2.2673422
 4 0.06093674     X.1  2.4007376
 5 0.48162959     X.1 -2.3118850
 6 0.50780007     X.1 -0.7307929
```

So you want one variable for the Y coordinate (I'm using variable `U` here), one variable for the X coordinate (using `X` here), and a 3rd variable that indicates whether the observation belongs to cluster 1 or cluster 2 (variable `cluster` here).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I would like the plot be in the same panel. I mean do not separate the two plot. That is. I want to join them in one plot.

Comment: Just remove `+ facet_wrap(~cluster)` from the last line of code. I added the faceting because the points are all exactly in the same location, so they get mapped on top of one another.

Comment: Yes. Because they are almost the same. But my data is quite complex which I think will work good. I will try and see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It gave me exactly the same shape for each cluster. My data shows a different two shapes. So they are completely different. That is, when I run your code, it does not show the data shape.

Comment: That, is your plot is exactly the same (left and right but different colour). The total shape of each cluster is must be different.

Comment: Yes, but I can only use the data generated from your code, and I don't know its purpose. Matrix `X` results in 2 columns of data of 2000 observations. The values in the 2 columns are the same throughout. Is that correct?

Comment: No it is not the same. They are different. You can change the value of the mean and standard deviation of each group as you like. I will edit the code to make them so different.

Comment: I sent my graph so you can see how the data has different shape. I tried your code but give me different shape from this.

Comment: I see. You actually want to use `X.1` and `X.2` as your X and Y coordinates... So what is indicating whether an observation belongs in cluster 1 or 2? Also - your code is certifiably giving me something different than what you're getting. The 2 columns for X are exactly the same on my end. You may have other code going on that is affecting this that I"m not privy to.

Comment: I used X[,1] and X[,2] with your code but gave me the same colour for all data.

Comment: Yes, your comments is true.

Comment: I tried all the way to specific the value of each cluster but it shows the value on x-axis and based on that gave me the colour.