# scatter plot using ggplot2 of 3 variables (mixture) gives wrong result in r when using ifelse

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]I

tried to plot a scatter plot of three different variables using ggplot2. I would like each variable to have its own icon plot shape and color. However, the code gives thta the two of the tree plots are quite the same which is wrong!!

```
## generate the data
  N=2000
  dim=dim
  U=runif(N, min=0,max=1)
  #set.seed(123)
  #U=runif(N, min=0,max=1)
  X = matrix(NA, nrow=N, ncol=3)
  for (i in 1:N){
    if(U[i] < 0.5){
      X[i,] <- rCopula(1,claytonCopula(1,dim=3)) ## must be lower tail
    } else if (U[i] < 0.3) {
      X[i,] <- rCopula(1,gumbelCopula(7,dim=3)) ## must be upper tail
    }else{
      X[i,] <- rCopula(1,frankCopula(2,dim=3))
    }
  }
```

This code is similar to the one used here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ueka.png):[How to get a scatter plot of mixture data with different shape and colour for each distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083035/how-to-get-a-scatter-plot-of-mixture-data-with-different-shape-and-colour-for-ea])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ueka.png). However, it only works for two dimensions.

```
###################################################################
df = data.frame(
  sh_of = ifelse(U < 0.3, "Gumbel", ifelse( U < 0.5, "Clayton", "Frank")),
  x = X[, 1],
  y = X[, 2],
  z = X[, 3]
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y,z=z, colour = sh_of, shape = sh_of)) +
  geom_point()+scale_shape_manual(values=c(12,25,14)) + ggtitle("")+theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="black", face="italic", size=15, hjust=0.5))
```

Comment: Can you post the plot it produces? I am not aware of any `ggplot2` functions to make 3d plots, unless you are using `plotly` or some extension. Do you know of any documentation for this `z` aesthetic?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. To be honest I didn't know any documentation for z. Z is my third variable.

Comment: I will send the graph right now.

Comment: @juod I added the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ggplot2` is ignoring the `z` aesthetic, and for some reason adding `facet_wrap(~sh_of)`. If you really want to use `ggplot2`, you could bin the `z` dimension and use `facet_wrap(~z)` to draw "slices" of it. But to get an actual 3d plot, you'll need another package - I would recommend `plotly` ([3d scatterplot documentation](https://plot.ly/r/3d-scatter-plots/)) or `rgl` ([plot3d function](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/rgl/html/plot3d.html))

Comment: sorry, I could not understand "bin the z"? could you please explain more.

Comment: I meant that you could plot several frames of 2d scatterplots, where each frame would contain only point with certain range of `z` values: e.g. first frame would have only points with 0<z<0.1, second frame would have only points with 0.1<z<0.2... As if you were going through slices across the z-dimension, think of x-ray images across the brain, for example. But I'm not sure if that will fit your needs.

Comment: All what I need is to plot each variable with different color and shape based on its value from generated data.

Comment: Then use one of the other packages I suggested, it's the simplest solution.